# Why ExecuteReader() only returns the first row?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqldatareader

hope you all well. I tried to get all rows from table and then put them into a list but the ExecuteReader only returns the first row. is it something to do with the list or is there any other techniques? can someone help please!

```
using (SqlConnection mySqlConnection = new SqlConnection(AppConfiguration.ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SelectCity", mySqlConnection);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter prmcountrycode = new SqlParameter("@countrycode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            prmcountrycode.Value = countrycode;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(prmcountrycode);

            mySqlConnection.Open();
            List<string> allcitiesnames = new List<string>();

            using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                int count = myReader.FieldCount;
                if (myReader.Read())
                {
                     allcitiesnames.Add(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("CityName")));

                }
                else
                {
                    mySqlConnection.Close();
                    InsertNewCity(countrycode);

                }

                myReader.Close();
            }
            mySqlConnection.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
while(myReader.Read())
{
  allcitiesnames.Add(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("CityName")));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all rows directly you have to use `SqlDataAdapter` and use `DataTable` fill it with data from database and return the `DataTable` from it.

`SqlDataReader` gets rows one by one in seqeuntial manner, see [here how to use SqlDataAdapter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter), Also see this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

### Example:

```
        // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
        DataTable t = new DataTable();

         // 1
        // Open connection
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Connection string here"))
        {
          c.Open();
          // 2
          // Create new DataAdapter
          using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter("Query Here", c))
             {
               // 3
               // Fill DataTable with data
               a.Fill(t);

             }
         }
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely... this is actually a better way to do it, and it also works well with sprocs.  A caution:  Just ensure you don't return a data adapter.  A data adapter is a connected object, a data reader is not.

Answer (score 0):

Basically `SqlDataReader` designed to read the database rows one at a time

Change

```
if (myReader.Read())
{
    allcitiesnames.Add(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("CityName")));
}
else
{
    mySqlConnection.Close();
    InsertNewCity(countrycode);

}
```

to

```
while(myReader.Read())
{
    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        allcitiesnames.Add(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("CityName")));
    }
    else
    {
        mySqlConnection.Close();
        InsertNewCity(countrycode);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Instead of Two Calls to Database I will suggest you to Change Your procedure as

```
create procedure SelectCity
    @countrycode nvarchar(50)
as 
begin    
    if exists(select top 1 CountryCode from mytable where CountryCode=@countrycode)
    begin
        select * from mytable 
    end
else
begin
    insert into mytable (CountryCode)
    values (@countryCode)
end
end
```

So this will select all if exists else insert it into table
and Rest of Will be Same by using `SqlDataReader` with `ExecuteReader`

Comment: I keep getting Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed. with your solution although i removed "myReader.Close();".

Thanks for the effort

Comment: @muteb are your trying to insert cityname if it is not exists ??

Comment: no trying to select if exists.if it doesn't exist call it from api and insert them into the database. the insertion works fine and stores into the database.

Comment: thank you opened my mind to this:

 using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                
                if (myReader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        allcitiesnames.Add(myReader.GetString(myReader.GetOrdinal("CityName")));
                    }
                }
                else
                
                {
                    mySqlConnection.Close();
                    InsertNewCity(countrycode);
                }
                
            }

Comment: Don't close the reader explicitly, put it into a `using () { }` block instead.

Comment: This code calls `myReader.Read()` twice each loop. It's throwing away every other record.